# Regular Expression - White Space

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to remove white spaces from values in a list.  Can you help me figure out the correct way to use a regex to do this? ( MY CSV is 2 columns

So Far:

```
import csv
import re

f = open('my_file_path')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)

b = csv_f.replace(' ', '')

print b

f.close()                - Is the above syntax correct, still getting an error. hmm
```

Comment: Replace does not modify a string, it *returns* a copy with the white spaces removed: `a = "a b"; b=a.replace(' ', ''); -> a == "a b" and b == "ab"`.

Answer (score 0):

if you do `b = csv_f.replace(' ', '')` it will remove all the whitespaces. If you do spilt like this,

```
sentence = ' hello  world'
" ".join(sentence.split())
>>> 'hello world'
```

Otherwise, you can use `str.strip()` function, you can get rid of space in the beginning and ending. If you could say exactly where you want to remove spaces I can help you. (There is other ways using python pandas, if you're reading in files and try to perform cleaning. I recommend you to read about that too).